# counting for specific value in pandas .value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I currently have a columns with two gender values, male = 1, and female = 2 and I would like to count and display the value next gender.

```py
Gender = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

when I used this code

```py
df['Gender'].value_counts()
```

I got the following output:

```
1 6
2 5

Gender dType is int64
```

but I was looking for the following result. However I kept getting a different output than the following:-

```
The total number of Male: 6
The total number of Female: 5
```

This was print that I used but it kept giving me an error. I think I may need your help with this one. Thank you in advance.

```py
print('The total number of Male:' df[Gender].value_counts(),'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

value_counts returns the series. So you have to access a specific value by using position at which it is present, you can try the following:

> Input 1 :

```
Gender = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]
series = df['Gender'].value_counts() 
print(series)
```

Output 1 :

```
1    6
2    5
dtype: int64
```

> Input : 2

```
print('The total number of Males : ', series[1])
print('The total number of Female : ', series[2]
```

Output 2

```
The total number of Males : 6
The total number of Females : 5
```